# Selecting positive certain values from a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to select the x, y values from an array of the same, for example :

```
xy = [[0.0, 3], [0.1, 1], [0.2, -1]]
```

where y > 0, so the output should be

```
array[ [0.0, 3], [0.1, 1]]
```

I tried something like

```
[x for x in xy if y>0]
```

, but it returns the following error :

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Don't you mean `>= 0`?

Comment: @Simon : I suppose your issue is resolved, please mark the answer accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slice the object to compare just the y values and use the resulting boolean mask:

```
In [12]:
xy[xy[:,1]>0]

Out[12]:
array([[ 0. ,  3. ],
       [ 0.1,  1. ]])
```

Here `xy[:,1]` gives you just the `y` values:

```
In [13]:
xy[:,1]

Out[13]:
array([ 3.,  1., -1.])
```

Here is the resultant boolean mask:

```
In [14]:
xy[:,1] > 0

Out[14]:
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ans = [i for i in xy if i[1] > 0]
```

Output :

```
[[0.0, 3], [0.1, 1]]
```

Comment: or `[[x, y] for x, y in xy if y > 0]`

Comment: Thank you, this works but leaves me with a list of arrays.

Comment: What is your expected output ? @Simon

Comment: In the end, I want to fit the y-values using fit_curve, so before I was converting the 2D array into 1D arrays x and y using [:,0] and [:,1]

Comment: You can do this : `numpy.array(ans).flatten() `, if you want a single list.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `itertools.compress`:

```
from itertools import compress

xy = [[0.0, 3], [0.1, 1], [0.2, -1]]
res = compress(xy, [item[1] > 0 for item in xy])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list(res)
[[0.0, 3], [0.1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[x for x in xy if x[1]>0]
```

Comment: this answer is the same as Jarvis' answer